# await requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, async-await, webgl

Can JS await requestAnimationFrame() inline?

Because before user can see message (is drawn to screen) "*Compiling vertex shader ...*"
JS get stuck in compiling shader (for multiple seconds).

I **prefer inlining** than creating multiple functions for each heavy function,
and than continue on next line without calling next function.

Also making it as **generator is not possible** as it would need controling function to execute it and  common errors from compiler will be hard to catch. (errors on production version not dev)

```
document.getElementById("errorLog").innerHTML += "Compiling vertex shader ... ";
await requestAnimationFrame(); // <= HERE
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.error(`ERROR compiling vertex shader! \n ${gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader)}`);
}
document.getElementById("errorLog").innerHTML += "DONE<br/>";

document.getElementById("errorLog").innerHTML += "Compiling fragment shader ... ";
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.error(`ERROR compiling fragment shader! \n ${gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader)}`);
}
document.getElementById("errorLog").innerHTML += "DONE<br/>";
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't work like this. Better use `setTimeout`

Comment: requestAnimationFrame() returns a long integer, so it can't be await-ed. However, you can technically wrap it in a Promise and await the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to wait, and are not using the return value for anything, you can simply use a Promise around it to make it `await`able:

```
await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));
```

or even

```
await new Promise(requestAnimationFrame)
```

And you can also make a function for that, for example

```
function promiseNextFrame(){
    return new Promise( resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve) ); 
}
```

and then use `await promiseNextFrame()`